# Single Pop up can add text for multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have multiple users in my application. In the list of users, every user has a button for data submission. Data will be submitted in pop up. I have to use jquery to generate popup and jquery-json combination to save data in database. 
   Can I use single popup click on multiple buttons? Please suggest me.

e.g.

```
 <table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="#efead8" style="border:#FFCC00 1px solid;">
      <tr><th bgcolor="#cccccc" align="right">&nbsp;S.No.&nbsp;</th><th bgcolor="#cccccc" align="left">&nbsp;Client&nbsp;</th><th bgcolor="#cccccc" align="center">&nbsp;Cost List&nbsp;</th><th bgcolor="#cccccc" align="center">&nbsp;Action&nbsp;</th><tr>';
        foreach($arrclient as $k => $v)
             $strPrint.='<tr><td align="right">&nbsp;'.++$i.'&nbsp;</td><td align="left">&nbsp;'.$v.'&nbsp;</td><td align="center">&nbsp;Cost List&nbsp;</td><td align="center">&nbsp;<input type="button" name="new_ci" id="new_ci" value="New cost list" />&nbsp;</td><tr>';

        $strPrint.='</table>';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Can I use single popup click on multiple buttons?" can you explain it more?

Comment: single popup click on multiple buttons? wat it means, if u want to use single method on all popup pass id in click method.

Comment: Yeah Meraj is right, but how I use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $strPrint.='<tr><td align="right">&nbsp;'.++$i.'&nbsp;</td><td align="left">&nbsp;'.$v.'&nbsp;</td><td align="center">&nbsp;Cost List&nbsp;</td><td align="center">&nbsp;<input type="button" name="new_ci" id="new_ci" value="New cost list" onclick="OpenPopup(this)" />&nbsp;</td><tr>';


function(obj)
{
 // do wat ever u want
}
```